# How to hide a class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to hide a product shipping class. If there is a free postmail delivery:
If you take this product to cart and to cart page :
https://lehorot-derech.co.il/product/dubbel/
if this shipping class is in cart :

```
shipping_method_0_advanced_free_shipping
"משלוח בדואר רשום ללא תוספת תשלום ב-0"
```

then i want to hide this shipping class:

```
shipping_method_0_flexible_shipping_15_1
"משלוח בדואר רשום: ₪24"
```

I found this code but i don't now how to adjust it. Anybody help plz.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_hide_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );\
function custom_hide_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) \{\
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item  ) \{\
        $product = $cart_item[ 'data' ]; // The WC_Product object\
        if( $product->get_shipping_class_id() == 513 ) \{ // <== ID OF MY SHIPPING_CLASS\
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:2'] ); // Removing specific shipping method\
            break; // we stop the loop\
        \}\
    \}\
    return $rates;\
\}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot hide class, you can remove it:

1. [How to do it in JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)
2. [How to do it in JS](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_class.asp)

UPD: best solution which i can suppose it check if exist class shipping_method_0_advanced_free_shipping, then remove shipping_method_0_flexible_shipping_15_1 if not leave second, example

```
if ($( "#yourelement" ).hasClass("shipping_method_0_advanced_free_shipping")) {
   $( "#yourelement" ).remove('.shipping_method_0_flexible_shipping_15_1');
} else {
   $("#yourelement" ).attr("class","shipping_method_0_flexible_shipping_15_1");
}
```

it meets condition above

Comment: i want to hide not remove

Comment: what do you mean hide ?

Comment: i mean when one class is active then other should be disable